# Pandas Index Repeating

Tags: python, html, pandas, csv, web

Im trying to print the first element of "Contract Name" however it prints 25 times (the total number of rows) and i i search for another index within the range it doesnt work. I downloaded it to a csv file in order to check the index and it is fine there but not in the code.

[CSV View][1]

````
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(delay=10, browser='chrome') 
url = "https://etherscan.io/contractsVerified"
info = scraper.get(url).text
soup = beauty(info, "html.parser")

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'table table-hover'})
table_body = table.find('tbody')
rows = table_body.find_all('tr')

l = []
for tr in rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text for tr in td]
    l.append(row)
    gatu = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=["Address","Contract Name","Compiler","Version","Balance","Txns","Setting","Verified","Audited","License"])
    x = gatu.iloc[0]
    row_1 = gatu["Contract Name"].iloc[0]
    print(x)
    print (row_1)```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwWkd.png
````

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code rewritten to do what you want; notice how all rows are saved in python rows, then a pandas data frame is created around them. Then you can query whatever you want from the pandas data frame.

```
import cloudscraper
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as beauty
import pandas as pd

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(delay=10, browser='chrome') 
url = "https://etherscan.io/contractsVerified"
info = scraper.get(url).text
soup = beauty(info, "html.parser")

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'table table-hover'})
table_body = table.find('tbody')
rows = table_body.find_all('tr')

all_rows = []
for tr in rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr1.text for tr1 in td]
    all_rows.append(row)

# Load all rows into data frame object
df = pd.DataFrame(all_rows, columns=["Address","Contract Name","Compiler","Version","Balance","Txns","Setting","Verified","Audited","License"])
#print(df) # Print entire data frame
#print("\n")
print(df["Contract Name"]) # Print all Contract Names
print("\n")
print(df["Contract Name"].iloc[6]) # Print a specific Contract Name based on row number
```

Output:

```
0                   AngelInu
1     ShadowGuardianContract
2             YogiesItemShop
3              ReeferMadness
4             degentoonbirdz
5              HittingMyself
6              COMMUNITYDOGE
7                 MetaKellys
8                    Address
9               TheModernMan
10                     PRINT
11                  TestPass
12            ElectroApeClub
13              WakaranaiInu
14                   ZoroInu
15                 FFGOBLINS
16                   IllDoIt
17                  capybara
18            MultiNftMarket
19                  OtherDAO
20                 FFGOBLINS
21          FourHundredDrums
22                   Culture
23                ShibNaruto
24                     GAL96
Name: Contract Name, dtype: object


COMMUNITYDOGE
```